# Trouble showing nav div when scroll past header

Tags: jquery, scroll

This is the code I've got already:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    /*Scrolls to whichever element is clicked if is has .scrollPage class */
    $('.scrollPage').click(function() {
        var elementClicked = $(this).attr("href");
        var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
        $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination-0}, 500 );
        return false;
    });

    $('#backToTop').hide();
    $('#sideNav').hide();

    var headerHeight = $('#header').height();   

    /* Detect when page is scrolled */
    $(document).scroll(function(){ 
        var scrolledpx = parseInt($(document).scrollTop()); 
        if (scrolledpx > headerHeight) {
            $("#backToTop").fadeIn(500);
            $("#sideNav").fadeIn(500);
        }
        else if (scrolledpx < headerHeight) {
            $("#backToTop").fadeOut(500);
            $("#sideNav").fadeOut(500);         
        }
    });


});
```

The corresponding HTML for #backToTop is:

```
<div id="backToTop">
Top
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.backToTop {
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that #backToTop doesn't show when I scroll below the header, but when I click on a link to scroll to a particular section (which works fine), it seems to leave a space for #backToTop (i.e. it just shifts the page down by one line), but doesn't show it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, very simple. I was using .backToTop in the CSS rather than #backToTop.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Fcden/

Your css should be:

```
#backToTop {
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}
```

because `backToTop` is the `id` (not the `class`) assigned to the div,